# How to write .htaccess rewrite rule to solve 404 error when angularjs html5mode is enabled

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to AngularJS and PHP. In the application i am working on, I have enabled html5mode in angularjs using following things:-

```
-- Added base href in /myapp/index.html
<base href="http://localhost/myapp/" />

-- Added following at the end of config function.
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

When I access my application using following url: http://localhost/myapp ,
It does not append any # in browser url. I can navigate to any other route successfully. Route url is http://localhost/myapp/category/1

But when I refresh the page, above url gives me 404 error. I understood that, server trying to find file at location /myapp/category/1. I read at other places writing .htaccess rule will solve this problem. I tried all those options. Nothing worked for me.

I am using xampp and location of .htaccess file is **/htdocs/myapp/.htaccess**
.htaccess file is accessible, because if I add any junk data in it, url throw error.

Please help me on this. I need server to return url as it is so that angularjs can route pages correctly. Please help me to write .htaccess rule. mod_rewrite is already enabled in httpd.conf file of apache.

Answer (score 0):

I can able to find solution for this. My .htaccess file will look like below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(map|css¦js|html|png)
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```